# Redirecting domains, sub domains and single pages on Siteground

Tags: domains, htaccess, redirects, subdomain

I'm having serious issues with Siteground to get my redirects working. They did work on another hoster so it is possible. However, that server configuration was very different so I cannot copy what we had there.
SG has been messing up my site all day long and now says they don't know if they can do it.

I'm not very good with redirect rules so hoping that someone here can point me in the right direction.

We have one WordPress installation and one main domain to which all redirect.
There are a ton of different domains (.net, org., etc) that just forward to the main site, let's say: `https://www.example.com`
No issues with that. DNS point to Siteground IP and on SG these domains are entered as 'parked domains'.
Forwarding and SSL all work.

This is what needs to be done:

1. wholesale.example.com -> example.com/wholesale
2. example.net -> example.com/kids
3. example.net/*.* (any page on example.net except for #4) ->  example.com/kids
4. example.net/wholesale -> example.com/page3
5. wholesale.example.net -> example.com/page3

During the day I have seen various combinations working. but never all at once.
SG said we need example.net as an 'addon domain' which creates a folder /example.net in the root.
Then they also created a folder /wholesale which makes #5 work but creates a 403 forbidden error for #1

Any ideas what the correct set up would need to be?

Comment: Do you know what software Sitegorund uses for hosting management?   Based on you talking about "add on domain", it sounds like cPanel to me.

Comment: "During the day I have seen various combinations working. but never all at once." - This doesn't seem to make sense, unless someone was actually changing the redirects/code throughout the day, the redirects should remain consistent? "they also created a folder /wholesale which makes #5 work but creates a 403 forbidden error for #1" - they must have done more than "create a folder"? To clarify, these are all intended to be _external redirects_ ? I can't see why they suggested an "addon domain" - from what you've described above you would only seem to need "parked" domains.

Comment: However, if you are using WordPress then you won't be able to create all these redirects using cPanel alone - without at least editing your `.htaccess` file at some point. By default, cPanel will create these redirects at the end of the file, but they need to go at the start of the file, _before_ any WordPress specific directives. When cPanel creates redirects, it simply edits the `.htaccess` file for you. Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file in your question.

Comment: Siteground uses CPanel. 
@MrWhite: SG had various people working it during the day.

Comment: SG finally solved (almost) it with person #6 taking a look.

1.wholesale.example.com -> example.com/wholesale
Defined as subdomain with redirect and htaccess rules in root.

2.example.net -> example.com/kids
Addon domain with its own folder and htacces.

3.example.net/. (any page on example.net except for #4) -> example.com/kids
Not solved. Decided we can live with it for now.

4.example.net/wholesale -> example.com/page3
Folder wholesale in new folder with htaccess

5. wholesale.example.net -> example.com/page3
Subdomain in Cpanel with redirect.

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to add the htaccess rules here.

Comment: Not allowed by whom?